# Как запретить повторную анимацию?

Tags: jquery

Проблема такая (код это для меню все просходит нормально, но если проводить мышкой по этому меню быстро вверх и вниз, анимация будет повторятся столько раз, сколько провели мышкой вверх и вниз).

Задача (я не знаю, как это предотвратить, то есть запретить повторную анимацию, пока не закончилась первая (то есть пользователь провел по меню 3 раза, а оно должно отреагировать один раз)). Код ниже

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navigation-text-menu ul li a').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $('img', this).fadeIn(500);
        }).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#165b95",
            paddingLeft: '50px'
        }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(function () {
            $('img', this).fadeOut(300);
        }).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#2b2a2a",
            paddingLeft: 15
        }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Да и еще, если кто знает, как это сделать, пожалуйста, каждой сторчке комментарий, чтобы я понимал, как это все осуществляется (не этот, а исправленный!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `jQuery` есть такое понятие, как очередь. В очереди помещаются все анимационные эффекты, которые должны произведены на странице. Вот и получается, если наводить три раза мышь, то в очередь записывается, что эффект выполняется три раза последовательно, друг за другом. тут два пути выхода:

1. воспользоваться методом `stop()`. у него есть два параметра первый - `clearQueue` (необязательный). если он имеет `true`, очищается очередь от всех анимационных эффектов. и второй параметр `gotoEnd` (необязательный) - доводит текущий анимационный эффект до конца, после чего вся очередь очищается. для Вашего случая, мне кажется подойдёт `stop(false, true)`.
2. и второй, *более* элегантный способ! есть метод `.queue()`, который позволяет создавать свои очереди и изменять уже существующие. Есть метод `.dequeue()`, который позволяет очищать наши (и не только очереди). Как я уже говорил Ваши анимационные эффекты записываются в очередь. Во внутреннюю очередь jQuery, носящую имя `fx`. следовательно, именно эту очередь нам и надо очистить. Вот и получаем, что сначала Вам надо добавить в очередь действие, а затем его удалить оттуда.

Значит решение достаточно простое. Если предыдущий эффект не был закончен до наступления нового события наведения - доводим предыдущий эффект до конца, а очередь очищаем. С анимацинным эффектом поступаем так: помещаем его в очередь `fx`, делаем необходимые действия, затем удаляем его из очереди `.dequeue('fx')`. Этими шагами Вы добьётесь, что очередь всегда будет пуста.

вроде, скрипт делает то, что нужно. я упростил Ваш код для большей наглядности.

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation-text-menu ul li a').hover(function(){
        $(this)
        .stop(true)
        .queue('fx', 
          function(){
            $(this)
             .css({'backgroundColor': '#165b95'})
             .animate({paddingLeft: '50px'}, 500)
             .dequeue('fx');
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this)
        .stop(true)
        .queue('fx',
          function(){
            $(this)
             .css({'backgroundColor': '#2b2a2a'})
             .animate({paddingLeft: '0px' }, 500)
             .dequeue('fx');
        });
    });
});
```

спасибо за внимание!

PS по поводу цвета фона. В методе `.animate()` применяются те CSS-свойства, которые принимают числовые значения и для которых переход от начального значения к конечному логичен. А как осуществить линейный, плавный переход от одного цвета к другому?

Comment: по поводу Вашего кода - приведите его немного в порядок. не совсем понятно чем обоснованно столь большое количество функций обратного вызова....

Comment: всмысле впорядок? просто возврат на исходное значение

Comment: смотрите примерно такой же эффект и у меня но он немного сложнее
http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1244
там сбоку горизонтальное меню понаводите как я вам говорил и поймете в чем суть

Comment: я конечно же хочу воспользоваться вторым способом

Comment: мне другое интересно - когда jquery сибирается фиксить:

"event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future."

Comment: понятно тогда. мне тогда не понятно зачем Вы используете `fadeIn()` второй раз для **уже** видимого элемента в функции для состояния, когда мышь отводится. у Вас при наведении следующая цепочка: проявляется элемент, проявляется изображение, увеличивается отступ. Значит для "отвода" мыши должно быть приблизительно следующее: элемент двигается обратно, исчезает изображение, затем исчезает сам элемент.

Comment: (ну кто-нибудь поможет мне я просто не знаю как вторым способом сделать а хочу пример я уже показал)
(не да это ерунда просто если использовать FadeOut начинает все исчезать окончательно и безповоротно а так нет)
читал даже документацию но не очень понял
желательно если кто мне напишет чтобы я сам разобрался по коду и на этом же примере

Comment: щас испробуем комментарии можешь добавить к своему коду

Comment: погоди цвет тоже плавно должен изменяться это не css  правило

Comment: кстати что такое fx  и чем его можно заменить кстати там не совсем то что мне надо мне надо так как на той ссылке

Comment: я же сказал, что немного упростил Ваш пример. эмммм.....Вы вообще читали то, что я писал в своём ответе?

Comment: да потому что у меня нет картинок!!!моё решение делает то, что Вам изначально нужно было - при многократном наведении эффект не выполняется многократно. Уже с картинками и остальным делай сами по аналогии. я за Вас этого делать не собираюсь. я описывал этот метод в своём ответе и пояснял значение `fx`. я считаю вопрос закрытым.

Comment: Так вот я думаю - в ближайших версиях хрома(и мб сафари тоже) все такие анимации будут вызывать ошибку. Разумно ли использовать эти функции?

Печально что проблеме уже не один день, проблема довольно важная, но решать ее не спешат.

Comment: а, кстати, можно поинтересоваться чем же мой эффект отличается от эффекта по ссылке?

Comment: Сам JQuery не юзаю уже оч.давно но, насколько помню, плавный переход цвета реализован в `jquery ui`

Answer (score -2):

все понятно кроме функции с параметром fx
ммм проблема да все работает т е к ссылкам а картинкам нет так как там идет обращение к $('img',this)
все равно эффект не тот как на ссылке
а я не считаю так эффект не тот как на ссылке поэтому вопрос не закрыт                отличается он тем что для каждой ссылки анимация там проходит до конца а у меня резко прекращается при наведении на другую давай по скайпу созвонимся

Comment: кстати я просто потестил метод .stop(true) b выяснилось что он выполняет также даже без метода .queue() так что здесь этот метод не работает

Comment: то, что он работает без метода `.queue()` это описано в моём ответе. я не писал, что этот метод используется в связке. этот метод в коде приведён для остановки предыдущего эффекта.

Comment: LeD4eG давайте созвонимся

Comment: а смысл нам созваниваться? тогда я предлагаю открыть скрипт того сайта и посмотреть как именно там реализовано. в общем так, вопрос был в том, как остановить повторную анимацию. моё решение её останавливает. вопрос закрыт!

Comment: блин а рейтинг зачем мне портить хотя ладно наплевать